# Can ISC-DHCP bind to Option 82 rather than Mac Addresses?

Tags: mac-address, isc-dhcp, dhcp-option

We use option 82 information to limit leases presently in ISC-DHCP using a spawn with statement for our billing subclass. This keeps a single household/business from obtaining more leases than they should.

The issue we have is ISC-DHCP ties leases to the mac address of the device getting the IP. When this happens and a user switches devices, they have to wait until the first lease expires before the new device can obtain a lease.

What we're wanting to do is tie leases to the option 82 information directly. With this, a user could have "computer a" get an IP, disconnect "computer a", hook up "computer b", and still be able to utilize the same IP on "computer b" as they had on "computer a".

Is such a thing possible with ISC-DHCP via its configuration?

Thanks,
Tim

Edit: We're considering writing something to actively monitor our logs for DHCP that would essentially remove old leases as necessary when new lease requests come in with the same Option 82 info but a different Mac than what already exists. This would be a big task for our environment, so doing so right in ISC-DHCP would be ideal.

Comment: Hey Tim, did you ever resolve this question? We've got a similar piece where we need to issue responses based upon the Gateway-IP request parameter.